# How to Combine to values into datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, concatenation, ssms-2014

How to combine two values into a datetime field

```
 Example value 1 = 2010-10-26 00:00:00.000 (datetime)
 Example value 2 = 1650 (varchar)

 Desire Result 2010-10-26 16:50:00.00
```

Comment: Could you explain logic to combine? Get date part from value1, get time part from value2?

Comment: Yes combine both value1 and value 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `datetime`s together in SQL Server.  The trick is getting the time from the second one:

```
select (value1 +
        cast(cast(stuff(value2, 3, 0, ':') as time) as datetime)
       )
```

Alternatively, if `value2` is an integer, you could do:

```
select dateadd(minute,
               (value2/100)*60 + value2%100,
               value1
              )
```

Comment: Thanks Gordan, thats perfect!